# Error When Importing From Sketchup 'Object' object has no attribute 'layers'

Tags: import

This is the error.

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\SketchUp_Importer\__init__.py", line 886, in execute
    context, **keywords)
  File "C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\SketchUp_Importer\__init__.py", line 185, in load
    self.write_duplicateable_groups()
  File "C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\SketchUp_Importer\__init__.py", line 245, in write_duplicateable_groups
    group=group)
  File "C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\SketchUp_Importer\__init__.py", line 614, in conponent_def_as_group
    ob.layers = 18 * [False] + [True] + [False]
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'layers'
```

I have issue to import to Blender and I am using the Sketchup importer add on to import the Sketchup skp file directly (link below). Some models import without issue and are really good, and some keep having this error. I have tried cleaning the models using the Sketchup Fix tool and Purge tools and same error still. Any ideas how to fix this? I have tried the export from Sketchup to Colada tool, but the models have issues with position accuracy using this, whereas the skp imports are much more accurate.

https://github.com/arindam-m/pyslapi/releases/tag/0.21